# How can I replace all the yes or nos in a vector with another word in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector whose only entries are yes or no. I need to replace each yes with "Institutional" and every no with "Retail".

I have tried for loops, ifelse statements, case_when and replace functions, all to no avail. They all still return the same vector full of yes and no.

Comment: gsub("yes","okay", x$whateverthevectoris)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905038/replace-values-in-a-vector-based-on-another-vector

Comment: You should have added the code you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
#Data
vec <- rep(c('yes','no'),10)
vec

[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes"
[18] "no"  "yes" "no" 

#Replace
vec[vec=='yes'] <- 'Institutional'
vec[vec=='no'] <- 'Retail'
vec

[1] "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"       
[7] "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"       
[13] "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"        "Institutional" "Retail"       
[19] "Institutional" "Retail"
```

Comment: ... and similar in motivation, a lookup could be used `c('yes'='Institutional', 'no'='Retail')[vec]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `ifelse` like below

```
v <- ifelse(v == "yes","Institutional","Retail")
```

or play some tricks with `factor`

```
v <- as.character(factor(v,levels=c("no","yes"), labels = c("Retail","Institutional")))
```

Comment: I think the `factor` idea is sound but it might be nice to be explicit about what level goes with which label - `factor(v, levels=c("No","Yes"), labels=c("Retail","Institutional"))` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for your advice, I updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately that returns a Named chr "Retail" (because the first entry in the vector is no, I assume)

Comment: @FrederickBernet Neither approach works? Could you show a piece of your data?