# How can I do a matching between two datasets with different amount of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, analysis

I have a dataset (PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID) with 16 ID categories. I want to match this 16 categories to the corresponding district codes (21). I want the rows corresponding to IDs to repeat when needed, the important thing is that each district has the corresponding information. The thing goes as it follows: ID A has the district 1, the ID B the 2, the C the 3, the D the 4, the E has the districts 5 and 6, the F has the district 7, the G the 8, the H the district 9, the ID I has the districts 10, 11 and 12; the J the 13, the K the 14, the L the 15, the M the 16, the N the 17, the O the 18 and 19, and the P the districts 20 and 21. I want to keep all the information contained in the PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID dataset. For this, some rows will be equal in everything but the district code.

I

```
# Assuming you have a column "ID" in PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID
# Create a new column "District_Code" based on the mapping
PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID$District_Code <- NA

# Mapping based on the information you provided
id_to_district_mapping <- c(
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3,
  D = 4,
  E = c(5, 6),
  F = 7,
  G = 8,
  H = 9,
  I = c(10, 11, 12),
  J = 13,
  K = 14,
  L = 15,
  M = 16,
  N = 17,
  O = c(18, 19),
  P = c(20, 21)
)

# Assign district codes based on the mapping
for (id in names(id_to_district_mapping)) {
  PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID$District_Code[PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID$ID == id] <- id_to_district_mapping[id]
}

# Duplicate rows based on the District_Code
PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID_duplicated <- PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID %>%
  unnest(cols = c(District_Code)) %>%
  mutate(CODDISTRIT = as.numeric(District_Code)) %>%
  dplyr::select(CODDISTRIT, ID, sumhourly_exceedances, sumdaily_exceedances, count, mean_value) %>%
  complete(CODDISTRIT, ID, fill = list(sumhourly_exceedances = 0, sumdaily_exceedances = 0, count = 0, mean_value = 0))
```

have been doing a bunch of things, similar to this, and nothing is working, because I always get 16 rows instead

Comment: This would be a much better question (and much easier to answer!) if your example was **minimal, reproducible, and verifiable**. Currently, it's not minimal with 16 categories and 21 district codes - 3 categories and 5 district codes would be plenty to get the idea across...

Comment: It's not reproducible because you only share `id_to_district_mapping`. If you would share 5 or 10 rows of `PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID` (just the relevant columns), that would give us some input to try solutions on. `dput()` is often the easiest way to share data reproducibly, `dput(PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID[1:8, "ID", drop = FALSE])` will make copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 8 rows of the ID column of your data. And lastly, please share the desired result for your small sample input so that we can verify that a solution is correct.

Comment: That said, the easiest approach for this type of problem is usually a merge/join. If you put your `id_to_district_mapping` mapping in a data frame with an `ID` column and a `district` column, the solution may be as simple as `merge(PRUEBAsummary_NO2_2019_ID, id_to_district_mapping_df)`. (Though there are other ways too.) You can see related questions like [How do I map a vector of values to another vector with my own custom map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18456968/903061) and [Replace values in a dataframe based on lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905038/903061)